# xgboost predictions are all 0?

Tags: boosting, spark-mllib

I ran xgboost4j for classification (in scala-spark), but when I did a sanity check on my predicted values, I got all zeroes. How do I change the threshold? I'm assuming there's a way to map probability outputs to 0-1 values.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I will try is to debug. Make sure that you have trained on the right data, right label, right split, and stuff like that.

If this still happens, there is the chance that there is a difference between your train and test split. Have a look on that.

Check what results you get in the train set, if you still have all 0 when predicting in train you definitely have a problem.

If you want to change a threshold, first you want to get the probabilities (something like predict_proba). And then filter base on your own threshold.

But right now it seems you have an error in your ML pipeline